# Xpath - find all cells in a table with a certain property

Tags: html, xpath

I have a table that is defined like this

```
<div class="wrap-4-columns product-list box">
```

(followed by a couple of levels of other divs)

Then the div with main content looks like this

```
<div class="product-inner-wrap">
   <div class="info-col grid-columns">
       Actual content
   </div>
</div>
```

Finally, on some of the cells, there is a span at the same level as the `<div class="info-col grid-columns">`

```
<span class="js-sale badge disrupter">Some text</span>
```

Currently the table has 4 columns with 6 cells. That is, the first row has four elements and the second row two elements. Row 1 column 3 (R1C3) and R2C2 have this span. I want to select the content of `<div class="info-col grid-columns">` of all cells with the span `<span class="js-sale badge disrupter">Some text</span>`

Can this be done?

`//div[@class="product-inner-wrap"]//div[@class="info-col grid-columns"]`...then what?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below `xpath` with multiple attributes.

```
//div[@class="product-inner-wrap"]//div[@class="info-col grid-columns"]//span[@class="js-sale badge disrupter"][contains(.,"Some text")]
```

Or

```
//div[@class="product-inner-wrap"]//div[@class="info-col grid-columns"]//span[contains(.,"Some text")]
```